# What is the relationship between correlation length and charge density wave order?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Hy, i am a physics (bsc) student and for a project work i need to evaluate some RXS measurment data, we try to find CDW order in YBCO. The evaluation part is all well and done i just can't make sense to the results as i dont understand what the correlation length regarding charge order means, and why is it important. Can anybody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if my answer is related to what you ask. I use Xray diffraction to probe charge density waves in solids. The correlation length is directly related to the inverse of the FWHM (full width at half maximum) of the CDW's diffraction satellite. Is this what you asked about?

Comment: Not exactly, but thank you. So i can calculate the corr. length and everything, the only thing that i don't understand is why the correlation length is important in CDW? What infomration does it contain, Basicly why do we calcule the correlation length?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer here so I can add a picture.
One thing you can extract from a correlation length measurement is the transition temperature.
This is not only true for charge density wave, but for any second order phase transition.
Here's a figure I found in an article :
[image]

Link of the article :
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/1989/T25/007/meta

You may have access to other information using the correlation length, but I don't have any other in mind right now.